# How to adjust height of full image as background fit to chrome/any browser without cropping it?

Tags: html, css

I am beginner to css and want to set an image on background.  I am trying to set image height fit to screen without cropping image. I simply want scrollbar to get disappeared.  here is  code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .bgimage {
            background-position: center center;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
background-image:  url('Images/56216134.jpg');
background-size: 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 100%;
height: 1000px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="bgimage">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: o]

[image]

Comment: Use the height: 100%; as used the width.

Comment: height should be in percentage and `100%`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is set your `div` height equals to 100% of your `form` (if your `form` is 100% height of `body`).

Then you'll have to set your `background-image` **size** property to "**contain**"  :

```
background-size: contain;
```

> The keyword contain will resize the background image to make sure it remains fully visible.

More informations [about background-size property](https://cssreference.io/property/background-size/).

Here is a **code snippet example** :

```css
html, body, form{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.capebretonpost.com/media/photologue/photos/cache/yv-23052017-billcurry-1_large.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bgimage">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

If you want your image to take your full width, then you can use `background-size: cover;` as following :

```css
html, body, form{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.bgimage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url('https://www.capebretonpost.com/media/photologue/photos/cache/yv-23052017-billcurry-1_large.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bgimage">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Here it is @Emmy :)

Comment: Thank you @André DS

Comment: If it helps, don't forget to upvote useful answers, and mark it as "answer" if it solves the problem. Keep coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Resize the background image to cover the entire container, even if it has to stretch the image or cut a little bit off one of the edges with the following:

```
.bgimage { background-size: cover; }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, You can use `height:100vh` and `background-size: 100% 100%;`

Please read about [100vh](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp)

Let me know further clarification.

Hope this help.

```css
        .bgimage {
    background-position: center center;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-image: url(https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff);
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    min-height: 100vh;
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title>Full height demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="bgimage">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please provide me your actual code or link, So i will try to fixed.

Answer (score 0):

try this `background-size` it stretch the background image and cover the whole background without cropping. Even width and height set according to your needs.

```
 .bgimage { 
         background-size:100% 100%;
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did use the class **.bgImage**, set its width to `width: 100%` and in javascript use page load function to set its **height** to `window.innerHeight;`

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! `background-size: cover;` is what you're looking for I think, this will make sure that the div is covered and show most of the image too (just cuts off as little as possible in order to cover the div).

And you can include `height: 100vh` in order to make it full screen height.

```css
body { margin: 0; } /* This is just for the example - to make it full screen*/

.bgimage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/500/1000');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bgimage">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```

I have also included a version below that uses the shorthand version of all the background properties - I prefer to use this as I find it easier and clearer to read. But you can use them separately if you like - makes no difference. You can read about it here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

```css
body { margin: 0; } /* This is just for the example - to make it full screen*/

.bgimage {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  
  background: url('https://picsum.photos/500/1000') center/cover no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div class="bgimage">
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
```